# Generate 100K dataset that the features and class are only 0 and 1 and is linear

Tags: python, dataframe

Is there a way to generate a dataset that only contains 0 and 1? I want to create a dataset that has 4 features with 0s and 1s and also this dataset to be labelled with 0 and 1. The data should be 50% labelled as 0 and 50% labelled as 1 and to be linear.

Example of dataset:

```
A B C D Class
0 0 0 0   0
0 0 0 1   1
0 0 1 1   1
1 1 1 1   0
```

Comment: How do you expect the values to be linear with only 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can cook your task down to generating random integers in range [0,15] and map them back to their binary represantation. Then you can give them your labels for example as 0 for numbers <= 7 and 1 else or 0 for odd numbers and 1 else, or some custom mapping.